# Django REST ViewSet create

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a viewset for employees where I want to add a create definition, such that I can set employer=request.user.pk and add the employee (user).

I've tried making a create definition (see code below) but the serializer is always invalid so it returns status 400. I don't know if it's me but there seems to be a lack of documentation on the create function so I can't figure out how to do it correctly. Any ideas?

```
class EmployeeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.queryset.filter(employer=request.user.pk)
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            CustomUser.objects.create_user(**serializer.validated_data)
            return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response({'status': 'Bad Request',
                         'message': serializer.is_valid()},
                          status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the **`perform_create`** method as,

```
class EmployeeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return CustomUser.objects.filter(employer=self.request.user.pk)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(employer=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! Just wondering, why is list replaced with get_queryset, and where can I find some documentation on this? I struggled to find any guidelines.

Comment: ViewSet's are using `get_queryset` in all its ***actions*** (create, update, partial_update etc) and internally `list` method call the `get_queryset()` too.

Comment: DRF doc itself should be your first reference. Sometimes, source code digging also helps.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out. Btw, your last edit broke the code.

Comment: Removing `queryset` attribute will not break the code as we are overriding the `get_queryset` method. Can I ask what error you have got?

Comment: AssertionError: `base_name` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.queryset` attribute.

Comment: @SJ19 Thanks for the update. I reverted the changes